# Good DVD ripper - for Divx

Tags: dvd, encoding, ripping, avi, divx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DVD ripper for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/4387/dvd-ripper-for-windows)
>   [Rip DVD on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/16742/rip-dvd-on-linux)
>   [Best Mac OS X DVD Ripper](https://superuser.com/questions/18428/best-mac-os-x-dvd-ripper)

I'm currently going through my DVD collection, and digitising it, to allow me to watch it on a media streamer
(I'm NOT a filesharer!!)

I want to know what software i should use, to convert my DVD's to AVI divx format.

I currently use Xilisoft DVD ripper, however this creates a "letterbox" at the top and bottom of the file - and there doesn't seem to be a way to turn this off.

I'm a novice at video encoding, so would need something fairly simple / well documented.

Comment: For windows? http://superuser.com/questions/4387/dvd-ripper-for-windows

Comment: For linux? http://superuser.com/questions/16742/rip-dvd-on-linux

Comment: For os x? http://superuser.com/questions/18428/best-mac-os-x-dvd-ripper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handbrake all the way. Open source, free, and available on every major platform.

http://handbrake.fr/

Answer (score 3):

To your original question, as you already have a copy of Xillisoft I am trying to do a solution without requiring anything extra

---

Look on the right settings column. There is a option saying something like target aspect ratio. If you do match original, it will create the file to whatever your source is.

Comment: +1 for helping use the software he currently uses and knows.

Answer (score 0):

decrypting with [RipIt4me](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RipIt4Me) or [DVDFab HD Decrypter](http://www.dvdfab.com/free.htm)

and encoding with [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/)

[image]

Not the easiest one but easy enough and powerful.