# What software/method can I use to make Matroska dump of DVD under Linux?

Tags: linux, dvd, encoding, ripping, matroska

I have set of DVD disks. I'd like to rip them to .mkv files, but with all information - i.e. all subtitles, and all audio tracks.

Is there any tool on Linux that I could use to do it? I found some [Gentoo howto](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Ripping_DVD_to_Matroska_and_H.264) about ripping, but it requires writing shell scripts, and I'd rather use something with clickable interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says at [Rip DVD on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/16742/rip-dvd-on-linux), Handbrake is probably the best if you don't want to mess with the command line. It handles mkv fine, and I know of no reason it wouldn't handle multiple audio and subtitle tracks.

Comment: Testing it now. From first look, it looks like it can do what I need.

Comment: Its nearly perfect. The one thing that it apparently can't do is convert bitmap subtitles to text ones - like for example ogmrip does.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't do OCR. Subtitleripper can do that, but it is CLI, and the GUI, KSubtitleripper, hasn't updated since 2005, so I don't know if it even works on a modern system